# C# threading issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, unmanaged

Are there some general advice about using multithreading when calling `unmanaged` code?

I randomly receive **access violation errors** and obviously digging into that `unmanaged` code doesn't make much sense.

Are there some approaches I could try instead of putting these calls into some sort of a `critical section` to remove violation errors?

Comment: Access violation errors aren't *necessarily* the result of multithreading issues, at least not when you're writing unsafe code. Are you explicitly creating multiple threads, or are you just assuming that it must be the problem? What does the debugger tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether the unmanaged component you are calling is programmed threadsafe or not.

If you are getting access violations only when calling this code in parallel it looks like the component you are using is not threadsafe.

Use the C# `lock()` statement to make it secure:

```
private static readonly myLockObject = new object();

...

lock (myLockObject)
{
   CallMyUnsafeCode();
}
```

Comment: Well, I eventually meant that when was talking about `critical sections`. Thanks, anyway